# How to center after pseudo-elements?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I have a list of elements , I have added after element (vertical line) , I would like to center it and it should be **responsive.**

Here is what I want 
  [image]

Here is my solution

```css
.profile_card-bottom {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 64px;
}

li::after {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.15s ease-in-out;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  float: left;
  background-color: #979797;
  width: 1px;
  opacity: 0.1;
  height: 77px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 13px;
  right: -57px;
}

li:nth-child(3n)::after {
  display: none;
}

li:nth-child(4n)::after {
  display: none;
}

.likes,
.following,
.followers,
.follow {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
}

.btn-follow {
  background: $button-color;
  border-radius: 100px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  height: 92px;
  width: 268px;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 4.2px;
  position: relative;
  right: 37px;
  top: 9px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.assets-count {
  font-size: 48px;
  color: $li-span-color;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.assets-title {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: $h1-span-color;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  line-height: 11px;
  font-weight: $base-font-weight;
}


}
```

```html
<ul class="profile_card-bottom">
  <li class="likes"><span class="assets-count">124</span><span class="assets-title">Likes</span></li>
  <li class="following"><span class="assets-count">727</span><span class="assets-title">Following</span></li>
  <li class="followers"><span class="assets-count">4437</span><span class="assets-title">Followers</span></li>
  <li class="follow"><button class="btn-follow">Follow</button></li>
</ul>
```

Unfortunatelly my solution is not giving me the result I want,

What am I doing wrong in my solution? any help will be apreciated , Thanks

Comment: It's not clear to me what is wrong. Do you want those lines in between two numbers? If yes, you positioned it absolute so you can place the line wherever you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It Will work with responsive, Try this code

```css
.profile_card-bottom {
     display: flex;
     justify-content: space-between;
     padding: 0;
   }

   li {
     display: inline-flex;
     flex: 1 1 auto;
     -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
     flex-flow: row wrap;
     -webkit-align-items: center;
     align-items: center;
     position: relative;
        font-family: sans-serif;

   }

   li:not(:last-child):after {
     content: '';
     display: block;
     background-color: #ccc;
     width: 1px;
     opacity: 1;
     margin: 0 auto;
     height: 100%;
     position: absolute;
     right: 0;
   }

   li span {  
     display: flex;
     flex: 1 100%;  
     justify-content: center;
   }

   .btn-follow {
     background: #FFA640;
     border-radius: 50px;
     border: none;
     outline: none;
     font-size: 3vh;
     letter-spacing: 1px;
     color: #FFFFFF;
     font-weight: 600;   
     text-transform: uppercase;
      display: flex;
     flex: 1 80%;  
     justify-content: center;
     padding: 7px 15px;
     margin: 0 3px;
   }

   .assets-count {
     font-size: 4.5vh;
     color: #FFA640;
     letter-spacing: 0;
     font-weight: 400;
   }

   .assets-title {
     font-size: 2.5vh;
     color: #8298B9;
     letter-spacing: 0;
     font-weight: 200;
   }
```

```html
<ul class="profile_card-bottom">
    <li class="likes"><span class="assets-count">124</span><span class="assets-title">Likes</span></li>
    <li class="following"><span class="assets-count">727</span><span class="assets-title">Following</span></li>
    <li class="followers"><span class="assets-count">4437</span><span class="assets-title">Followers</span></li>
    <li class="follow"><button class="btn-follow">Follow</button></li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Mr Feroz I think your method was the best out of the rest I tested, bravo !, its responsive at it best , I need your contact lool

Comment: @user9964622 Thanks, you can touch with me 'firoz.mansoori8800@gmail.com'.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might misunderstand where the [`:after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) generated content ends up in the document flow.

> The pseudo-elements generated by ::before and ::after are contained by the element's formatting box...

So the after element is not actually placed *after* the `<li>`, but at the end of the `<li>`'s child nodes.

```css
.profile_card-bottom {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

li {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

li:not(:last-child):after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  background-color: #979797;
  width: 1px;
  opacity: 1;
  height: 77px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="profile_card-bottom">
  <li class="likes"><span class="assets-count">124</span><span class="assets-title">Likes</span></li>
  <li class="following"><span class="assets-count">727</span><span class="assets-title">Following</span></li>
  <li class="followers"><span class="assets-count">4437</span><span class="assets-title">Followers</span></li>
  <li class="follow"><button class="btn-follow">Follow</button></li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanantion really helps , I will test your solution too

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use `div` instead of `span` so you don't need to use CSS for span to make it block (flex). Also, use `li:nth-child(-n + 2)::after` instead of separating style for last two li with new rule.

See below Snippet:

```css
* {
 font-family: "calibri"; 
}
.profile_card-bottom {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

li {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}


li:nth-child(-n + 2)::after {
 content: '';
  display: block;
  background-color: #979797;
  width: 1px;
  opacity: 0.1;
  height: 77px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
}

li:nth-child(3n)::after {
  display: none;
}

li:nth-child(4n)::after {
  display: none;
}

li span {  
  display: block;
}

.btn-follow {
  background: #FFA640;
  border-radius: 100px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  height: 50px;
  width: 180px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 4.2px;
  position: relative;
  right: 37px;
  top: 9px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.assets-count {
  font-size: 38px;
  color: #FFA640;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.assets-title {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #8298B9;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  line-height: 11px;
  font-weight: 200;
}
```

```html
<ul class="profile_card-bottom">
  <li class="likes"><div><span class="assets-count">124</span><span class="assets-title">Likes</span></div></li>
  <li class="following"><div><span class="assets-count">727</span><span class="assets-title">Following</span></div></li>
  <li class="followers"><div><span class="assets-count">4437</span><span class="assets-title">Followers</span></div></li>
  <li class="follow"><button class="btn-follow">Follow</button></li>
</ul>
```

You can also test it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nimittshah/j9837uks/)

P.S. - I have changed the color and fonts to look like provided image;

Comment: Hii Nomit , let me check now I will accept if everything goes okay, thanks for help